# Type instability in random data with specified distribution

Tags: julia

I want to generate data from a linear model with noise (Y = X*w + e) where I can specify the distributions of input vector X and scalar noise e. For this, I specify the below struct

```
using Distributions

struct NoisyLinearDataGenerator
    x_dist::ContinuousMultivariateDistribution
    noise_dist::ContinuousUnivariateDistribution
    weights::Vector{Float64}
end
```

and a function to generate N points from it:

```
function generate(nl::NoisyLinearDataGenerator, N)
    x = rand(nl.x_dist, N)'
    e = rand(nl.noise_dist, N)
    return x, x*nl.weights + e
end
```

This seems to be working, however not type stable, as

```
nl = NoisyLinearDataGenerator(MvNormal(5, 1.0), Normal(), ones(5))

@code_warntype generate(nl,1)
```

yields

```
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(generate, false)
  nl::NoisyLinearDataGenerator
  N::Int64
  x::Any
  e::Any

Body::Tuple{Any,Any}
1 ─ %1  = Base.getproperty(nl, :x_dist)::Distribution{Multivariate,Continuous}
│   %2  = Main.rand(%1, N)::Any
│         (x = Base.adjoint(%2))
│   %4  = Base.getproperty(nl, :noise_dist)::Distribution{Univariate,Continuous}
│         (e = Main.rand(%4, N))
│   %6  = x::Any
│   %7  = x::Any
│   %8  = Base.getproperty(nl, :weights)::Array{Float64,1}
│   %9  = (%7 * %8)::Any
│   %10 = (%9 + e)::Any
│   %11 = Core.tuple(%6, %10)::Tuple{Any,Any}
└──       return %11
```

I am not sure why this is, since I would expect the type of the sampled data to be specified by using `ContinuousMultivariateDistribution` and `ContinuousUnivariateDistribution`.

What is leading to type instability here and what should a type stable implementation look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `ContinuousMultivariateDistribution` and `ContinuousUnivariateDistribution` are abstract types. While your knowledge of statistics tells you that they probably should return `Float64`, there is no guarantee on a language level that someone won't implement, say, a `ContinuousUnivariateDistribution` that returns some other object. Therefore the compiler can't know that *all* `ContinuousUnivariateDistribution` produces any particular type.

For example, I might write:

```
struct BadDistribution <: ContinuousUnivariateDistribution end
Base.rand(::BadDistribution, ::Integer) = nothing
```

Now, you could make a `NoisyLinearDataGenerator` containing a `BadDistribution` as `x_dist`. What would the output type be then?

In other words, the output of `generate` simply **can't** be predicted only from its input types.

To solve this, you need to either specify **specific** distributions for your new type, or else make your new type parametric. In Julia, whenever we have a field of a type that cannot be specified to a concrete type, we usually leave it as a type parameter. Thus, one possible solution is this:

```
using Distributions

struct NoisyLinearDataGenerator{X,N}
    x_dist::X
    noise_dist::N
    weights::Vector{Float64}

    function NoisyLinearDataGenerator{X,N}(x::X, n::N, w::Vector{Float64}) where {
                                    X <: ContinuousMultivariateDistribution,
                                    N <: ContinuousUnivariateDistribution}
        return new{X,N}(x,n,w)
    end
end

function NoisyLinearDataGenerator(x::X, n::N, w::Vector{Float64}) where {
                                X <: ContinuousMultivariateDistribution,
                                N <: ContinuousUnivariateDistribution}
    return NoisyLinearDataGenerator{X,N}(x,n,w)
end

function generate(nl::NoisyLinearDataGenerator, N)
    x = rand(nl.x_dist, N)'
    e = rand(nl.noise_dist, N)
    return x, x*nl.weights + e
end
nl = NoisyLinearDataGenerator(MvNormal(5, 1.0), Normal(), ones(5))
```

Here, the type of `nl` is `NoisyLinearDataGenerator{MvNormal{Float64,PDMats.ScalMat{Float64},FillArrays.Zeros{Float64,1,Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}},Normal{Float64}}` (yes, I know, awful to read), but its type contain all information needed for the compiler to fully predict the output type of `generate`.